# Using Python and Flask

Tags: python-3.x

Python with Flask
This is my code:

```
word=input("Type Something: ")
listofwords=word.split()
wordfreq = []
for w in listofwords:
    wordfreq.append(listofwords.count(w))
    print("Word: "+str(listofwords)+ "\n")
    print("Count: "+str(wordfreq) + "\n")
```

My code works fine. My only problem is that it prints it out horizontally:
Word: ['is', 'the', 'bus', 'at', 'the', 'terminal']
Count: [1, 2, 1, 1, 2, 1]

How do I have my results printout vertically like this:
Word    Count
"is"    1
"the"   2
"bus"   1
"at"    1
"the"   2
"terminal" 1

Also, which parts of my code should I put under "tr" and "td" in the table section of my html. I already have Word and Count under "th" and it works fine.

Answer (score 1):

In python 3.x: You must call additional the function:

```
print()
```

For example:

```
for w in listofwords:
    wordfreq.append(listofwords.count(w))
    print("Word: "+str(listofwords))
    print()
    print("Count: "+str(wordfreq))
    print()
```

More information you can get [here](https://docs.python.org/3.0/whatsnew/3.0.html).